# How to find equivalent resistance in following question

Tags: resistance

I am solving objective questions from my book but the main problem is that it doesn't have solutions and in following question I don't know what type of question is this. First I am thinking its Wheatstone bridge related but its not. And resistance are in series but its not. So please tell me what type of question is this and how to solve it.

[image]

Here's one I draw before but above one is confusing.

[image]

Comment: Did you try redrawing it?

Comment: Yes I try but totally puzzled. I can draw where connection also has resistance but here not.

Comment: Do you feel like sharing any of your tries so that we can tell you where you went wrong?

Comment: First of all I give names to all points from A to F. Then I try to redraw like any other question but I am unable.

Comment: Did you fold your nodes properly?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to fold in this case

Comment: Here's a clue - count the independent nodes in the circuit and what do you get. Then ask yourself how many ways you can arrange 3 resistors with these nodes.

Comment: What do you mean by independent nodes and how it helps?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh, try picking one node and highlighting it in red. Then pick another and highlight it in blue,  and so on. Once you've identified all the individual nodes, you'll find it easier to analyze the circuit (trust us on this).

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the name of this type of questions

Comment: Pretend the wires are pieces of string, grip the battery terminals, and pull apart.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmYrRr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now why was that a problem?  ( lack of numbering Nodes? )

Comment: @MichelKeijzers look more closely at your original circuit. Every resistor has V1+ at one end and V1- at the other. They are all in parallel, just drawn in a way to confuse you.

Comment: @Trevor_G Sorry I removed my comment because I saw that they are indeed equal :-)

Comment: How you changed them into parallel?

Comment: I identified Node 1 and 2 at each end of each resistor and redrew.  You can do this with more complex ccts by drawing  nodes in more logical positions then connecting between same nodes.  This cct has only 2 nodes but 5 dots, so 3 are redundant.  remember this. Nodes must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Re-drawing these circuits helps a great deal to find a simple solution - Andy makes a good suggestion to reduce the apparent number of nodes.
At first glance, it appears that there are four nodes...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPt5Tw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Andy suggests that **Node 1** is not independent from **Node 3** - they are the same. And similarly, **Node 2** is the same as **Node 4**.
So there are really only **two nodes** in this circuit. One of them connects to the "+" end of the battery, the other connects to the "-" end of the battery.

No one would publish a circuit diagram like that shown above. It is a book exercise to help you reduce circuits to their simplest form. Becoming adept at this skill is an important one for anyone dealing with circuits.

Comment: Node 1 and 3, node 2 and 4 same but how to proceed further?

Comment: What is the benefit of finding independent nodes?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh Once you realize that **Node 1** and **Node 3** collapse to a single node, then you should see that R1 & R2 are in parallel. And the junction point of R1 & R2 is *the same* as the "-" end of the battery. And the collapsed **Node 1, Node 3** is the "+" end of the battery.